# How to transform eloquent relation object?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

We have following models -

**Post**

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | title | text | creator | status | etc |
----------------------------------------------
|    |       |      |         |        |     |
----------------------------------------------

creator -> belongsTo User

group -> belongsTo group
```

**User**

```
posts -> hasMany Posts

avatar -> hasOne Media
```

**Media**

```
user -> belongsTo User
```

**Group**

```
post - belongsTo Post
```

When I fetch posts using eloquent I can use transform function to transform post attributes but unable to transform relations in the Post collections.

```
$posts = Post::where('status', 'active')
            ->with(['creator.avatar','group'])
            ->get();

$posts->transform(function($post) {
    $post->title = 'Transformed'; // works
    $post->creator->avatar = ['path'=>'/avatar/','file_name'=>'a.png']; // does not work
});
```

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `$post->creator`, you're essentially calling `$post->getRelation('creator')` via a "magic method".

This is important because it means that you're setting a property on the object returned by the `getRelation` method, you **are not** updating the creator relationship by reference - so when you call `getRelation('creator')` again, the original relationship value is returned.

Therefore, to achieve what you want to accomplish, you need to overwrite the `creator` relation value:

```php
$posts->transform(function ($post) {
    $post->title = 'Transformed';

    $creator = $post->creator;

    $creator->avatar = [
        'path' => '/avatar/',
        'file_name' => 'a.png'
    ];

    $post->setRelation('creator', $creator); // or $post->creator = $creator;
});
```